# Remove extra space on Brightcove video player

Tags: video, video-player, brightcove

I have media on broghtcove which doesn't have any head and tail black space.
But on Video player it automatically adds it up.

Here is the video with those extra black space on top and bottom. This doesn't show up on full screen model

[image]

Here are the video setting available for brightcove, I don't see an option to fix this from there.
[image]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

With this version of Brightcove's player the default player size is defined in the "template" the player is based on. The template name is displayed under the player name in the publishing module. Alternatively [set the player size in the embed code](https://support.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/docs/resizing-video-player-modifying-publishing-code):

```
<param name="width" value="480" />
<param name="height" value="270" />
```